# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40)

Tags: exc-bad-access, swift4.1, xcode9.4

I am running a code with webRTC. I am not posting code because I really don't know the point where it is getting crashed. It is almost thousands of lines of code. I want to know where exactly the code is crashing. Is there any tool or any way to exactly get the line of code where it crashed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When your app crashed, Xcode should've shown the line which caused the crash. That should give you some clues.

Essentially a EXC_BAD_ACCESS is when your trying to access an object that's already been deallocated. So this means your problem might also be earlier in the code and not exactly at the line where it crashed.

This [website](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544) shows a couple of ways that might help you figure out what's the problem.

Hope this helps!